# all imports seem to geo code

Tags: import, geocoding

I never check the geocode box when importing. Yet, I found that even small imports were taking a long time. I ran strace on the php process and saw lots of lookups to google. So I disabled both the mapping provider and geocoding provider globally, re-ran the import and it went through in a fraction of the time.

Next, I took a closer look at the code that is triggered based on the geo coding checkbox:

The file: Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php contains:

```
 public function import($onDuplicate, &$values, $doGeocodeAddress = FALSE) {
    $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
    $this->_unparsedStreetAddressContacts = array();
    if (!$doGeocodeAddress) {
      // CRM-5854, reset the geocode method to null to prevent geocoding
      $config->geocodeMethod = NULL;
    }
```

In other words, if geo code checkbox is unchecked, the $doGeocodeAddress is set to false. If it is set to false, then we set `$config->geocodeMethod = NULL;`

Hm. Could this possibly work? If you set a property on a singleton locally in a function, it seems like it would not be available outside the function.

However, this "fix" [has been in place for years](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-5854) so I'm asking this question as a sanity check before opening a ticket.

Maybe something changed in the behavior of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is bug, but not for the reasons I thought.

In short: the addition of MagicMerge seems to be the culprit, resulting in changed behavior when geocodeMethod is set to NULL.

Long answer:

First, setting the property of a singleton in one function, does result in it persisting even in other functions. The singleton really does act like a global variable. That's how this has worked all the way up to 4.7.

However, in 4.7 [MagicMerge was introduced](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16373) to streamline the configuration object.

This approach added __get and __set functions to handle properties that are not defined.

Now, if a property (like geocodeMethod) is set, it is added to the cache (`$this->cache[$name] = $v;`). So far so good.

However, when it is retrieved, it only comes from the cache if it is set:

```
if (isset($this->cache[$k])) {
  return $this->cache[$k];
}
```

Oops. If we set it to NULL it will never be retrieved from the cache and will always be retrieved using the function `CRM_Utils_Geocode::getProviderClass`

Comment: I've opened (and submitted a patch for) an upstream bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20381